# How do I Speed up VBA Copy and Insert code

Tags: excel, vba, optimization

Steps:

-User-form is initialized asking for two inputs: New KPI and where to do add it, NewKPI.Value and CboKPI.Value respectively (Not a problem).

-A new line is added in the reference based on the above. User is asked to input formulas into the reference line (Not a problem).

-The code below is executed. After every CboKPI.Value a new line is inserted. The reference line is copied into it (with formulas and formatting). In addition, the information from the row before it is copied into it to remove the "Reference" values.

In short, the code in step 3 is far too slow. I have about 2500 rows and the code takes more then **25 min to run** now. I am looking to speed up my code, with **explanation** please (so I can learn, I am new to coding on VBA).

I have already tried the following, disabled: screen-updating, automatic calculation, events displaying page breaks while the code is executing. I also understand that inserting and copying codes in vba is slow (don't know why relative to other procedures).

Thanks in advance.

```
Dim RowRef As Long, MSP As Worksheet, LastRowRef As Long, i As Long, NewRow As Long

'Finds the row where the New KPI is
 RowRef = .Columns("I").Find(what:=NewKPI.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, 
 MatchCase:=True, LookAt:=xlWhole).Row

'Finds where the Reference lines end
 LastRowRef = .Columns("B").Find(what:="Reference", LookIn:=xlValues, 
 SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookAt:=xlWhole).Row

 For i = .Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row To LastRowRef Step -1

'Finds lines where the "Add After" KPI is situated
 If .Cells(i, "I").Value = CboKPI.Value Then
    NewRow = i + 1

    'Adds a new line after "Add After" Kpi
    Rows(RowRef).EntireRow.Copy
    Rows(NewRow & ":" & NewRow).Insert shift:=xlDown

    .Range(.Cells(NewRow, "B"), .Cells(NewRow, "G")).Value = .Range(.Cells(i, "B"), .Cells(i, "G")).Value

End If
Next i
```

Comment: This appears to be full, working code that is looking to be optimized; it should be moved to code review.

Comment: You can also turn `Application.DisplayPageBreaks = False` and `Application.PrintCommunication = False`, that make a minor improvement. You might comment out this line: `Rows(RowRef).EntireRow.Copy`, it looks having no effect.

Comment: `Rows(RowRef).EntireRow.Copy` is there because it copies any formula I inputted into the reference row into every newly inserted row. Without it, my newly inserted rows will be empty without the name of the New KPI or the formulas surrounding it. I have already tried `Application.DisplayPageBreaks = False` and no improvement.  How will `Application.PrintCommunication = False` help?